# Problem in binding form with get method to a GetMapping controller

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to implement a html `form` with `GET` method in thymeleaf like below:

```
<form action="/SearchTerminal" method="get" >
      <label for="code">label</label>
      <input type="number" id="code" name="code" class="form-control" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ">Search</button>
</form>
```

and my controller is sth like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/SearchTerminal?code={code}")
    public String searchTerminal(@PathVariable("code") String code){
        ...
        return "edit-terminal";
    }
```

When I submit the search button, the controller warns `No mapping for GET /SearchTerminal` and I get `404` error.

I cannot figure it out what I am doing wrong since I have provided the correct url in my `GetMapping` and when I press Search button, `http://localhost:8081/SearchTerminal?code=10101010` url is generated.

p.s: I want to stick to `API Design principles` and do not want to use `post` method in my `form` since it has more `GET` like nature and does not create any `resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://localhost:8081/SearchTerminal?code=10101010
```

Here `code` is in the url but after `?` and it's actually query param. You don't need to specify this pattern is URL mapping. Just use this way

```
@GetMapping(value = "/SearchTerminal")
public String searchTerminal(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
...
   return "edit-terminal";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `@PathVariable`. It would be for mapping like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/SearchTerminal/{code}")
```

but in your case it should be

```
@GetMapping(value = "/SearchTerminal?code={code}")
public String searchTerminal(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
...
   return "edit-terminal";
}
```

Comment: So, which one is it? `/SearchTerminal?code=10101010` or `/terminal/SearchTerminal`? Sounds like two different urls.